# Log off session after x time in Windows

Tags: windows, command-line, shutdown

I utilize the `shutdown /s /t 10` command to turn-off my computer after a specific time interval.

I know that I can employ `shutdown /l` to log off from my session. So I attempted using `shutdown /l /t 10`, however, it didn't work.

So, what command should I use to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

For example you could use `ping 127.0.0.1 -n 6 > nul && shutdown /l`

This uses the ping command as a timer.

There are more options listed over at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1672338/how-to-sleep-for-five-seconds-in-a-batch-file-cmd